# C# from txt file to datagridview loading

Tags: c#, datagridview

> Kazım Unlu 14/10/1985 Turkey FARh+ 34568668275 Sht. Mehmet Emin
>   Street, No:1, Gocmenkoy,Istanbul,TURKEY

How can ı load this text from text file to datagridview?

Comment: do you know how to read text from text file?

Comment: How do you want to display this ?

Comment: dude, have you searched in the internet about how to read from file and working with datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

As this question is very broad and imo. consists of two questions I'll split it up. I would urge you to split the question up aswell, and add what you have tried so far (creating two new questions).

Reading from a txt file, here's a great example from msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

Once you've read the string from your txt file you should split it up. As the string is very incosistent this might be hard. There is no value to do the split on. Best you can do with it's current format is splitting on space (" ") or comma.

Now you can add your values to a datagridview. Here's a guide explaining how to use datagridviews:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview

Edit: sorry for the broad answer, but this is a really broad question.